# How to get primary keys

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a model

```
     public class Application : BaseModel, IApplication
     {
       [Key]
       public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

       public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

       public string ApplicationTypeId { get; set; }

       public List<AlternateSigningAuthority> AlternateSigningAuthorities { get; set; }

       public List<Land> Lands { get; set; }

     }
```

And another model

```
     public class Land : BaseModel, IEquatable<Land>/*, ILand*/
    {

       [Key]
        public int LandId { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("ApplicationId")]
        public int ApplicationId { get; set; }

        public int Unit { get; set; }
    }
```

Similary I have a model for AlternateSigningAuthority. I want to get Primary Keys of these models.

I have code which works for Application

```
           var type = typeof(Application);
           var properties = type.GetProperties();

           var property = properties
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute)));

            if (property != null)
            {
                string msg = "The Primary Key for the {0} class is the {1} property";
                Console.WriteLine(msg, type.Name, property.Name);
            }
```

AS soon as I add

```
    foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(false);
            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                if (attribute.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute))
                {
                    string msg = "The Primary Key for the {0} class is the {1} property";
                    Console.WriteLine(msg, type.Name, attribute.ToString());
                }
            }
```

I dont get Primary keys. I want to use Application Model to get keys for other models.

Comment: *Which* `Application` do you seach for `Key`? Can you be confused with this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get \[key\] property from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835926/get-key-property-from-viewmodel)

Comment: @Szeki- I went through the link you posted before posting this question. Actually I am trying to get keys for all the models through one.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko- I have application model which has values and I am going to use those values to fetch me keys.So basically Application will go through its properties and get me the LandId and similarly key from Alternate Signing Authority

Answer (score 4):

You just need to call Attribute.GetCustomAttribute

```
AddressViewModel viewModelInstance=new AddressViewModel();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = viewModelInstance.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(KeyAttribute))
                as KeyAttribute;

            if (attribute != null) // This property has a KeyAttribute
            {
                // Do something, to read from the property:
                object val = property.GetValue(viewModelInstance);
            }
        }
```

I referred this link [Get [key] property from ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12835926/get-key-property-from-viewmodel?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I did check that post. My code is complaining at Attribute.GetCustomAttribute as Attribute doesnt have definition for GetCustomAttribute. So i broke the line  as var attribute= property.GetCustomAttributes(false);
                if (attribute.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute))    , but doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void WriteKeyProperty(Type classType)
{
    var properties = classType.GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var keyAttribute = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(KeyAttribute));
        if (keyAttribute == null) continue;
        const string msg = "The Primary Key for the {0} class is the {1} property";
        Console.WriteLine(msg, classType.Name, property.Name);
    }
}
```

And the call is

```
WriteKeyProperty(typeof(Application));
WriteKeyProperty(typeof(Land));
```

Comment: Is it possible that I do with Application and as Land and Alternative Properties will be there to get their primary key also. I am basically going to use the primary keys in an update function where I will have a function like  public async Task Update(Application oldApplication, Application updatedApplication)
        and I will be using OldApplication to get all primary keys.

Comment: Do you need to get the real value of the oldApplication key or just the key property name from this class?
You can do something like var properties = oldApplication.GetType().GetProperties(); and then use the above code to get the key property name

Comment: I am going to traverse through properties/values I have in oldApplication and i want to get keys like LandId and similarly want key for AlternateSigningAuthorities. The main goal is to use use those keys in linq query to make a generic function which will basically loop through all the values present in oldApplication and compare that with updatedApplication based on keys

Answer (score 0):

No sure what u are trying to do. your first code:

```
var property = properties
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                    .Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute)));
```

the property is PropertyInfo, therefore it gives you the name of the primary key. The a => a.GetType() == typeof(KeyAttribute) return the uniquely identifier of the class. So it is returning ApplicationId.

Your second code is not working because you are returning name of the CustomAttribute which is a object type.

I think your first code should work for all 3 classes.

Comment: Actually through my first code I am getting ApplicationId which is fine but then I want to loop through other properties from the same code and want to get LandID and key from AlternateSigningAuthority. I have  a function  public async Task Update(Application oldApplication, Application updatedApplication) and I am going to loop through oldApplication and with try to get all keys and will be using them to compare with UpdatedApplication in generic function. So I am trying to get all keys through Application.